# adding background color with bgcolor in html

Tags: html

I am trying to add background color to a input box with

```
 <td bgcolor = "color" >< foo>=</td>
```

my code look like this

```
 <td bgcolor = "#fa8072">< some text goes here <input size="20"
   name="pname" value="Bob"></td>
```

but I do not get any color.  Can someone clarify how to write this?

Comment: `<input style="background-color: #fa8072" size="20" name="panne" value="Bob">` ??

Comment: that does not add the color to the input box, just a block of color before the statement

Comment: This adds color to the input box itself [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8doftk5r/) but maybe i did not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, if you only have the above code, you don't have a `<table>` tag to go along with the `<td>`. Instead, use this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor = "#fa8072">
      < some text goes here 
      <input size="20" name="pname" value="Bob">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cp2xa4dp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<td style="background-color: #fa8072"> some text goes here <input size="20" name="pname" value="Bob"></td>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/suomyone/gvaxeu8g/

Ps. You're also missing the `<table>` and `<tr>` tags.

Comment: The `bgcolor=""` is correct. It's not working because he forgot his `<table>` tags.

Comment: Thanks k97513. I realized that when I was mocking up a JSFiddle demo. You beat me to it!